# jquerymobile - Footer is not placing in the bottom in firefox but works in chrome

Tags: php, jquery-mobile

You can see the code in http://jsfiddle.net/9ZBAS/48/

The footer is not fixing to the bottom in the firefox with switch useragent to iphone. but works well in the default browser (ie) firefox without useragent switch,
And also it works well in chrome with iphone useragent.

Any idea to fix this issue so it works both in FF and chrome as well as with iphone agent..?

Comment: Works fine on my firefox 13.0 and chrome 19.0.1084.56 m

Comment: did you tested on FF and chrome with Useragent switcher for iphone?

Comment: i didnt. but after testing with the useragent switcher i can tell the issue. by adding the class `ui-footer-fixed` mentioned by @dhaval seem to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although I could not find the exact reasy why `ui-footer-fixed` classes is not getting applied but below code does the trick.

```
   $(document).bind('pageinit',function(){
        if (navigator.platform == 'iPad' || navigator.platform == 'iPhone' || navigator.platform == 'iPod') {
            $("div[data-role=footer][data-position=fixed]").addClass("ui-footer-fixed");
        }
    });​
```

I have updated your fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/9ZBAS/55/

Comment: Do note that you should use `$(document).bind('pageinit')`, not `$(document).ready()` 
Refer to http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.1.0/docs/api/events.html

Comment: yes that is my mistake, i tested in the context of a single page so missed it.